# How to get tweets with given position of hashtag

Tags: python, tweepy

I try to get only Tweets with the hashtag #not, but only when the hashtag is at the end of the Tweet and not in the text. I am using tweepy.Cursor

This code already works. It gives me Tweets with #not, but doen't care where the #not is positioned.

```py
import tweepy
consumer_key = 'consumer key'
consumer_secret = 'consumer secret'
access_token = 'access token'
access_token_secret = 'access token secret'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#not",count=5,
                           lang="en",
                           since="2017-04-03").items():
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: You can use a regular expression to check that your hashtag is among a trailing set of hashtags:

```
import tweepy
import re

consumer_key = 'consumer key'
consumer_secret = 'consumer secret'
access_token = 'access token'
access_token_secret = 'access token secret'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

# Regular expression to check if tweet ends with our hashtag and maybe more hashtags
rgx = re.compile(r"#not(\s+#\w+)*$", re.IGNORECASE)
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#not",count=5,
                           lang="en",
                           since="2017-04-03").items():
    # Keep only tweets with the hashtag at the end
    if rgx.search(tweet.text):
        print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
```

---

You can just filter the tweets to keep only those matching your requirements:

```
import tweepy
consumer_key = 'consumer key'
consumer_secret = 'consumer secret'
access_token = 'access token'
access_token_secret = 'access token secret'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#not",count=5,
                           lang="en",
                           since="2017-04-03").items():
    # Keep only tweets with the hashtag at the end
    if tweet.text.lower().endswith('#not'):
        print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
```

Comment: But there can be multiple hashtags at the end of a Tweet. For example '#not #irony'. For my purposes it just has to be among the last. Is there not a solution in the tweepy package?

Comment: @maybeyourneighour I don't think there is any API specifically for that. You could traverse the `entities` list and check the positions, although a regular expression should do the job fine. I added a possible solution for that. Note none of this is taking into account the possibility of a link at the end (e.g. an image), you would have to do some more work if you want to support that (e.g. remove the link first or, again, analyse the `entities`).

Comment: okay, thank you. Links to an image are no problem because I filter these Tweets out anyway.

Comment: @maybeyourneighour Glad it helps. If you feel the answer solves your question, please consider marking it as accepted (green tick).